# Filter pandas group with if else condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

| ID | Tier1 | Tier2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | RF | B |
| 1111 | OK | B |
| 2222 | RF | B |
| 2222 | RF | E |
| 3333 | OK | B |
| 3333 | LO | B |

I need to cut down the table so the IDs are unique, but do so with the following hierarchy: RF>OK>LO for Tier1. Then B>E for Tier2.

So the expected output will be:

| ID | Tier1 | Tier2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | RF | B |
| 2222 | RF | B |
| 2222 | RF | E |
| 3333 | OK | B |

then:

| ID | Tier1 | Tier2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | RF | B |
| 2222 | RF | B |
| 3333 | OK | B |

I am struggling to figure out how to this. My initial attempt is to group the table with `grouped = df.groupby('ID')` and then:

```py
grouped = df.groupby('ID')
for key, group in grouped:
    check_rf = group['Tier1']=='RF'
    check_ok = group['Tier1']=='OK'
    if check_rf.any():
        group = group[group['Tier1']=='RF']
    elif check_ok.any():
        #and so on
```

I think this is working to filter each group, but I have no idea how the groups can then relate back to the parent table (df). And I am sure there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: good first post btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `groupby`+`agg` Pandas calls. Since the ordering `RF>OK>LO` and `B>E` are respectively compliant the (reverse) lexicographic ordering, you can use the trivial `min`/`max` functions for the aggregation (otherwise you can write your own custom min-max functions).
Here is how to do that (using a 2-pass filtering):

```py
tmp = df.groupby(['ID', 'Tier2']).agg(max).reset_index()      # Step 1
output = tmp.groupby(['ID', 'Tier1']).agg(min).reset_index()  # Step 2
```

Here is the result in `output`:

```
     ID Tier1 Tier2
0  1111    RF     B
1  2222    RF     B
2  3333    OK     B
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `pd.Categorical` & `drop_duplicates`

```
df['Tier1'] = pd.Categorical(df['Tier1'],['RF','OK','LO'],ordered=True)
df['Tier2'] = pd.Categorical(df['Tier2'],['B','E'],ordered=True)

df1 = df.sort_values(['Tier1','Tier2']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='first')

print(df1)

     ID Tier1 Tier2
0  1111    RF     B
2  2222    RF     B
4  3333    OK     B
```

---

Looking at `Tier1` you can see the ordering.

```
print(df['Tier1'])

0    RF
1    OK
2    RF
3    RF
4    OK
5    LO
Name: Tier1, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['RF' < 'OK' < 'LO']
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you!